# Determine if a specific activity in an application can be launched

Tags: android, android-activity, launch, securityexception

Applications can have any number of launchable activities.  I know how to get the list of these activities via PackageManager.

Is there a way to determine which activities can be launched via startActivity?

For example, the Documents To Go app has different activities that will start Word, Excel, Powerpoint, PDF, etc...  I am able to launch all o these just fine.

However, it also contains some activities that I am not able to launch with startActivity... If I attempt to do this I get a SecurityException.

I want to be able to determine which activities I can safely launch and which I cannot so I only present the user with a list of activities that I can safely launch from within my application...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create the intent with the parameters/data that you have and then use the package manager [resolveActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method to check for the activity which will be process your request.

Then check the permissions using [checkPermission()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkPermission%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of PackageManager.

HTH !

Comment: Unfortunately, the resolveActivity() method is only for implicit intents.  Since I have the package and class names for the activities I am launching (I am getting them through PackageManager) this method will not work for what I want to do.

I'm not having a problem FINDING the activity to launch.  The problem is that when I attempt to launch it via startActivity() I get a SecurityException error...

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: For what it's worth, the exact error I am getting from the SecurityException is this: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10600000 cmp=com.dataviz.docstogo/com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.WelcomeScreenActivity } from ProcessRecord{43565cb0 14660:com.magouyaware.appswipe/10043} (pid=14660, uid=10043) requires null

Comment: However, I can successfully launch other activities provided by the Docs To Go application.  So the question is, how can I determine which ones I can and cannot launch... (Note that using Docs To Go is just an example... This exact same problem ocurrs with many different apps)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably old hat to you but you can use this method:

```
getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                packageName);
```

Here is a way to get the package names of installed apps:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
                .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Launch Activity :"
                            + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));

        }
```

Comment: Thanks Nelson, but that does not actually answer my question.  The code you have finds an intent to launch the default activity for a given package.  My requirement is different.  I already have both the package name and class name for a given activity... In most cases I can launch it with an explicit intent.  However, in some cases I get a permission denied error...  All of my efforts to check if I have permission to launch the activity are ignored and I still get the SecurityException saying permission is denied.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. If you're able to catch the error that's probably as good as it gets. Sorry i couldn't help.